# In boost::asio how do you add timeout to the service loop?

Tags: boost-asio

Totally new to Boost::asio, am an old Unix Select type guy...

Trying to get access to select/epoll like timeout feature to break out of the event loop.
Adding a asio timer just calls my handler but does not allow me to break out of the service.run() loop. Don't want to delete the service just break out for a while and maybe restart it via service.run() later.

Along the same lines how do you remove a file descriptor from the service loop for a while, like EPOLL_CTL_DEL. Then add it back in later to be serviced again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

call [io_service.stop()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) from your `deadline_timer` handler, so `io_service.run()` will return control

Comment: Thanks I figured out like a minute after I posted the question, duh :(

But the second part still has me stumped! How can I remove a file descriptor (service object?) from the loop and later add it back in?

Comment: file descriptor = `boost::asio::io_service` object? what is the loop? pls clarify. if this helps - you declare `io_service` instance and call `io_service.run()`. it's the main loop. after you stopped it, you need to reset it (`io_service.reset()`), initialize all required async operations and run it again

Comment: +1 @Andy I updated your link to the current 1.45 version of boost

Comment: @Sam: tnx. google gives me always links to outdated boost documentation

Comment: you, me, and [everyone else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900676/tips-for-searching-the-boost-documentation) too :-)